# ScrollView inside ListView using ng-template issue

Tags: android, ios, layout, nativescript

I'm using `ng-template` + `ListView` to push dynamic content like images.

The `ListView` is inside the `ScrollView`.

**I need to scroll the entire page avoiding the double scroll caused by `ListView`.**

As workaround I have put `isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` on `ListView` to lock the content and prevent the scroll but the content is like "cutted" and I can't scroll anymore even if there are more images to show.

The code:

```
<ListView [items]="items" isUserInteractionEnabled="false">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                <GridLayout columns="auto" rows="*, *">
                    <GridLayout row="0" col="0" columns="auto" rows="*">
                        <Image col="0" row="0" stretch="fill" height="240" width="240" [src]="item.imageSquare.url"></Image>
                    </GridLayout>
                    <GridLayout row="1" col="0" columns="auto" rows="*">
                        <Image col="0" row="0" stretch="fill" height="160" width="540" [src]="item.imageRect.url"></Image>
                    </GridLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `ListView` I have tried to use `GridLayout` with `*ngFor` to create dynamic content

Comment: `GridLayout` had a problem so I have tried using `StackLayout` and I have partially resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You must give a high rating to the listview so that the performance goes well

```
<ListView height="150" [items]="items">
```

[doc](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/scroll-view#performance-tips)